# How to show a result message using Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have a search box on my index page, it is supposed to return a message if no result was found or redirect to result page if it succeeded.

Currently, if results were found it redirects to the new page, and if not will stay on the same page (index) but it does not show the message, just add the `mymessage` parameter to the page address as following

```
 www.address.com/index.jsp?mymessage=Sorry,No+results+were+found.
```

**Index**

```
 .......
  <s:property value="mymessage"/>
```

**SearchBox**

```
 public String search(){
    ....
        if(found)
            return "success";
        else
            return "failed;
 }
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <package name="Search" extends="default" namespace="/Search">
        <action name="*" method="{1}" class="com.myproject.myclasses.Search">

            <result name="success" type="tiles">search</result>

              <result name="failed" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">index</param>
                <param name="namespace">/</param>
                <param name="mymessage">${mymessage}</param>
            </result>

        </action>    
    </package>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think  <s:property> expects a getter getMyMessage() on your action class to populate 
values  can you try <s:property value="#request.mymessage" />

OR

Why can't you use action errors?

```
    public String search(){
    ....
    if(found) {
        return "success";
       }
    else {
           addActionError("No results found");
           return "failed;
       }
    }
```

Now in the index.jsp add the following,

```
    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
            <s:iterator value="actionErrors">
                 <s:property escape="false"/>
    </s:iterator>
      </s:if>
```

Comment: Lol at the escaping of your `<` and `> ` :) Just select the text and press CTRL+K, or click code button `{}`

Comment: @Andrea Ligios Thanks will take care next time :)